# Did the Wizengamot have any plans for defeating Grindelwald?

Tags: harry-potter

During the time before the defeat of Grindelwald, what would have happened as resolutions to the discussion of the Wizengamot council on how to defeat Grindelwald?

Comment: Would this qualify as future works?  There's a good chance it will be covered in one of the upcoming Fantastic Beasts movies...

Comment: @Forral - Yes, it would.

Answer (score 4):

## The Wizengamot is a court - they wouldn’t be responsible for that.

The Wizengamot is the court that British wizards are tried before if they’re accused of a crime. They wouldn’t be in any way responsible for planning to defeat Grindelwald.

> “They’ve demoted him from Chief Warlock on the Wizengamot – that’s the Wizard High Court – and they’re talking about taking away his Order of Merlin, First Class, too.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 5 (The Order of the Phoenix)*</sup></sub>

They could put Grindelwald on trial if he was captured, but actually bringing in criminals wasn’t their job. They functioned as any court would, with their job being judging whether wizards were guilty or not, and wouldn’t be the ones making plans to stop Grindelwald.

Comment: 11
no he didnot attack britain beacause dumbledore was present over there but hewas raising a big armyto takeover ministry of magic and to join the trio and as he did bad this and even tried to expose the statue of secrecy there were plannings on how to catch grindelwald from the other nations behalf so britain was also trying to help he other nations because ultimately he would end upattacking britain

Comment: @shebina Yes, wizarding authorities *did* discuss how to handle Grindelwald - the Wizengamot just wasn’t one of the authorities that would be responsible for that. They’re the wizard court - they aren’t in charge of that sort of thing. Another good example would be that the Department of Magical Games and Sports also wouldn’t have made plans for how best to apprehend Grindelwald - that’s not part of their job.

Comment: OKAY COULD YOU SUGGEST ON HOW TO DEFEAT GRINDELWALD IF THERE WASNT A DUMBLEDORE

Comment: @shebina Sure, but I don’t quite understand. Are you asking what the wizarding authorities planned to do before Dumbledore stepped in, or what would be a plausible way for Grindelwald to be defeated whether or not anyone actually planned on doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Wizengamot would have met to discuss Grindelwald.  For one thing a lot of them would have agreed with him, for another even though he was kind of the ringleader of the wizarding side of the war.  As far as i understand it he didn't really attack England.  If he did it wasn't just England it was the rest of Europe as well so it would be the ICW that would be having meetings.

Comment: no he didnot attack britain beacause dumbledore was present over there but hewas raising a big armyto takeover ministry of magic and to join the trio and as he did bad this and even tried to expose the statue of secrecy there were plannings on how to catch grindelwald from the other nations behalf so britain was also trying to help he other nations because ultimately he would end upattacking britain